# Keras, How build a custom loss t contains each pair from a distance matrix?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

### Problem definition

I have a distance matrix M. This distance `Matrix M` define s.t

```
[M]_i_j = D(batch_i,batch_j) where D is some distance function.
```

Therefor M is `batchsize X batchsize`.

Now for my `custom loss` I want to be able to calculate the sum of **almost every two pairs** in the matrix. For that I have another `matrix S`, this matrix defined as

```
[S]_i_j = 1 <=> batch_i and batch_j are **not** from the same class.
[S]_i_j = 0 <=> batch_i and batch_j are from the same class. 

Now I want to sum  `Max{0,[M]_i_s+[M]_i_n}`,
For all pairs s.t  [M]_i_s is cell s.t [S]_i_j = 0 and [M]_i_n is a cell s.t [S]_i_n =1
```

### The only options I have in mind are

1. Iterate over M and consider S while doing that. But in `Keras` I cannot iterate over a Tensor.
2. Create some how a matrix P with size of (batchsize)^2x(number of possible pairs) and then flat the matrix M to a vector  and calculate (flat(M))*P

The first one I cannot do. The 2nd one I didnt succed to create this matrix with `Tensor` Operations. I thought I can pre calculate this matrix P in advance and set it up as the prediction vector. But `Keras` force the `prediction` vector to be the same size as `batch`...

Any idea how to do 1 or 2 or any another Idea how to solves this problem in `Keras` ?

Thanks!